# Can't insert a boolean type in MySQL using Hibernate 4.3.0

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

guys!

I'm studying Hibernate with MySQL. I've created this model (it's in portuguese):

```
//imports
@Entity
@Table(name = "alunos", schema = "progweb")
public class Aluno {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;
    @Column(name = "nome")
    private String nome;
    @Column(name = "email")
    private String email;
    @Column(name = "endereco")
    private String endereco;
    @Column(name = "formado")
    private Boolean formado;

    //getters and setters
}
```

And I've created a class to test it:

```
//imports
public class CriaAluno {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Aluno aluno1 = new Aluno();

    aluno1.setNome("Jack");
    aluno1.setEmail("jack@gmail.com");
    aluno1.setEndereco("Av. dos Estados, 5001");
    aluno1.setFormado(true);
    System.out.println(aluno1.isFormado());

    // gravando registro
    EntityManagerFactory factory = Persistence
            .createEntityManagerFactory("aluno");
            EntityManager manager = factory.createEntityManager();
            manager.getTransaction().begin();
            manager.persist(aluno1);
            manager.getTransaction().commit();
            manager.close();
            System.out.println("Adicionado");

    }
}
```

Everything works fine, except by Boolean type; I got this in my MySQL database:

```
mysql> select * from alunos;
+----+----------------+-----------------------+---------+------+
| id | email          | endereco              | formado | nome |
+----+----------------+-----------------------+---------+------+
|  3 | jack@gmail.com | Av. dos Estados, 5001 |         | Jack |
+----+----------------+-----------------------+---------+------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

I have a null value in my database.

Comment: What is the datatype of `formado` in the table? It should be `TINYINT(1)`.

Comment: Try this : select formado+0 from alunos; It will show you 0 - false or 1 - true . see http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=43670

Comment: Thank you very much. Everything is ok, when I retrieve data back using hibernate "manager.find" method. With the command you have passed I could see the value true or false in tables.